# jQuery addClass problem

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using IE7. I have an input box as follows:

```
<input name="location" type="text" id="location" maxlength="512" size="20" class="editable text"/>
```

And I am trying to do the following:

```
$("#location").addClass('flagged');
```

But this wipes out all existing styling of the text box. The class 'flag' does not have any styling associated with it. The existing classes have the following CSS:

```
input.editable {
    height: 18px;
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
    padding-top: 0px; 
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    border:#FFFFCC 1px solid;
    margin:0px;
}

input.text {
    text-align:left;
    height:19px;
    width:100px;
}
```

If I manually add the class 'flagged' to the input box, all styling remains intact. In Firefox the jQuery `addClass()` does not clear all styling. Why is this happening in IE7?

**EDITED**
I've narrowed it down to this...

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) 
{
    String.prototype.trim = function(){
        // stuff
    }
}
```

The

```
String.prototype.trim = function(){}
```

declaration seems to be causing the problem. Any ideas?

**EDITED AGAIN** It seems to not like the fact that it's being called 'trim'. 2 Hours of the day well spent :|

Comment: have you tried adding styling to 'flagged' to see if it still clears the default styling?

Comment: [Here's a jsfiddle to play about with](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/agYGP/).  It works fine in Chrome, I don't have IE7 to test though.

Comment: @Town - tested your jsFiddle with my IE7, works fine.

Comment: this is so strange. what could possibly be causing this problem to occur for me when using addClass(), but not manually changing the class?

Comment: what is you `flagged` class style set??

Comment: @David Nguyen tell me about it. not using it by choice!

Comment: @diEcho there is no style for 'flagged'. i'm using it for a different purpose.

Comment: Very weird... what happens if you run this: `$("#location").attr('class', $("#location").attr('class') + ' flagged');` - also if you paste your full function that *might* help

Comment: Scott said it works fine, but it doesn't work for you chris? (the fiddle page)

Comment: @chrislegend r u using color `hex code` or `name`??

Comment: @chrislegend have you considered using `$.data()` since the flagged class is not for styling?

Comment: i appreciate the help everyone. i now know what the problem is  (and it doesn't look good). the page i am editing has many scripts on it (that i know nothing about), and removing them makes addClass() work like usual. now just to figure out which script, and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try seeing the classes assigned to the element, IE:

```
var myClass = $('#location').attr('class'); 

alert("classes = " + myClass);
```

Comment: well actually this idea offered the most help so far. pre addClass('flagged'): editable text, post addClass('flagged'): undefined

Answer (score 0):

from http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

> It's important to note that this
>   method does not replace a class. It
>   simply adds the class, appending it to
>   any which may already be assigned to
>   the elements.

So if you want to toggle a class try this out: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/